# React + Flux - How to avoid global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, reactjs-flux

I have been working on React/Flux and am confused over the declaration of variable outside the component as in below code.

**CounterComponent.js**

```
var count;
function getCount (){

}
var CounterComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return getCount();
  },
  render:function(){
  }
})
module.exports = CounterComponent;
```

As in the above code, the doubt is that the variable count and function getCount seem to be global here. Is it okay to have variables and functions declared here, outside the component or need to placed inside. This looks like global pollution.

Also, if we consider a store, have seen very examples as below, here also, the variable CHANGE_EVENT seem to be global, is that okay.

**CounterStore.js**

```
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
var MainStore = assign({},EventEmitter.prototype, {
  AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){ 
    var action = payload.action;
    switch(action.actionType){        
    }
  });
});
module.exports = MainStore;
```

I have searched for this answer, but couldnt get the right answer. From javascript perspective it looks like its polluting global, but what about in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the build system you use, if you use a system like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), then no variables would be global.

So if you do not use a bundler library, I suggest you to wrap your source code with a anonymous function, so that you wont pollute global namespace.

But I strongly suggest you to take a look with a modern approach using webpack which seems to be more popular within React and Flux community.

Comment: I am using browserify, but still, if I see in the dev tools, the js file, all the js files are concatenated and the variable's look like they are global. Isn't that so?

Comment: Nope, browserify does not just concanate files. The scope of variables are bound to files they are defined in. And you can only share variables across files using module.exports or require statements. That is a very fine property of browserify ( or webpack ) and allows you to write code without the fear of variable collisions. If you want to test it out, just open up your console and type the variable name you think that might be global. Thanks.

Comment: I have just edited my question and put in more details, specially module.exports thing. Can you please take a look and see if your answer still holds good.

Comment: Yeah, it still holds. With browserify and webpack, non of the variables are declared global unless you explicitly use window['variableName'] to set a variable to global scope. The whole reason for this is to prevent pollution of global namespace so you would control the functionality you expose, using module.exports.

Comment: So keep your files small and use file-wide global variables as much as you want to keep code cleaner and easier to reason with. You'll see similar use in many popular library source code. If you do not use webpack or browserify, then it is general practice to encapsulate whole code inside a Immediately Invoced Ananoymous Function to prevent global variables. Both approaches are still valid but the former one is more standart compliant, namely ES6 modules.

Comment: Well, sorry about that, I am still confused. Let's talk about CounterStore.js,  in this file, I have given MainStore to module.exports, so technically MainStore function should be the one which is kind of globally exposed and everything inside it is local to MainStore. 
But what about CHANGE_EVENT variable, its not in MainStore, so wouldn't it be global?

Comment: No problem. In fact, even MainStore is not global. You can only access it by explicitly calling require. Nothing in that file is global. Unless you explicitly set it to global windows variable (in browser environment) or global this variable (in node.js environment). So be safe, no variables ever be global.

Comment: Hmm..that sounds awesome. Need not worry about globals then :-) Thanks for the detailed explanation.